# Recoil - how to update an atom with socket.io correctly

Tags: react-native, recoiljs

I have to update an atom outside of an React Component (where I can't use hooks). What is the correct way to do this in order to get the updated value in my subscribing React Components with hooks like useRecoilState etc.?

Comment: It is quite difficult if you ask for an opinion, would be great to check what you have tried and start from that to give a better approach

Comment: Only way to do this is via a selector. Otherwise React won't be notified about the change.

Answer (score 3):

You generally don't want to run into this: I'd suggest to double check your approach first.

However, if you eventually still really need to **update atoms outside of React** Components you might give a try to [**Recoil Nexus**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recoil-nexus).

In the same file where you have your RecoilRoot you'll have something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import { RecoilRoot } from "recoil"
import RecoilNexus from 'recoil-nexus'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <RecoilNexus/>
      
      {/* ... */}
      
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
};


export default App;
```

Then where you need to read/update the values:

```
import yourAtom from './yourAtom'
import { getRecoil, setRecoil } from 'recoil-nexus'
```

Eventually you can get and set the values like this:

```
const loading = await getRecoil(loadingState)

setRecoil(loadingState, !loading)
```

That's it!

---

**Check this [CodeSandbox](https://githubbox.com/luisanton-io/simple-loader-with-nexus) for a live example.**

Comment: Thumbs up. Recoil Nexus is a great addition to recoil!

Comment: "You generally don't want to run into this" - do you mind explaining the "why" for that to someone new to recoil? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @hannojg In a nutshell, you want to make sure to use Recoil native hooks whenever possible: you don't want to abuse this bridge. I have even seen in some projects `getRecoil` and `setRecoil` inside components - which is a completely unnecessary abstraction.