# How to update a React/Recoil state array from web bluetooth subscription callbacks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, web-bluetooth, recoiljs

I am new to using React and Recoil and want to display real-time charts (using D3) from data that is gathered in real-time using the [Web Bluetooth API](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/).

In a nutshell, after calling `await myCharacteristic.startNotifications()` and `myCharacteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', handleNotifications)`, the `handleNotifications` callback is called each time a new value is notified from a Bluetooth device (see [this example](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/notifications-async-await.html)).

I am using hooks and tried to modify a recoil state from the callback (this was simplified to the extreme, I hope it is representative):

```
export const temperatureState = atom({
  key: 'temperature',
  default: 0
})

export function BluetoothControls() {
  const setTemperature = useSetRecoilState(temperatureState);

  const notify = async () => {
    ...
    temperatureCharacteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', event => {
      setTemperature(event.target.value.getInt16(0))
    }
  }
  return <button onClick={nofity}/>Start notifications</button>
}
```

This work fine if I want to display the latest value somewhere in the app. However, I am interested in keeping the last few (let's say 10) values in a circular buffer to draw a D3 chart.

I tried something along the lines of:

```
export const temperatureListState = atom({
  key: 'temperature-list',
  default: []
})

export function BluetoothControls() {
  const [temperatureList, setTemperatureList] = useRecoilState(temperatureListState);

  const notify = async () => {
    ...
    temperatureCharacteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', event => {
      let temperatureListCopy = temperatureList.map(x => x);
      temperatureListCopy.push(event.target.value.getInt16(0))
      if (temperatureListCopy.length > 10)
        temperatureListCopy.shift()
      setTemperatureList(temperatureListCopy)
    }
  }
  return <button onClick={nofity}/>Start notifications</button>
}
```

However, is is pretty clear that I am running into the issue [described here](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-everything) where the function is using an old version of `temperatureList` that is captured during render. As a result, `temperatureState` is always empty and then replaced with a list of one element.

How to maintain a consistent list in a React state/Recoil atom that is updated from an external callback? I think [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64123557/recoil-how-to-update-an-atom-with-socket-io-correctly) is a bit similar but I'd like to avoid using another extension like Recoil Nexus.

Answer (score 0):

`useSetRecoilState` accepts an updater function as an argument with the value to be updated as the first parameter:

```
export function BluetoothControls() {
  const setTemperatureList = useSetRecoilState(temperatureListState);

  const notify = async () => {
    ...
    temperatureCharacteristic.addEventListener('characteristicvaluechanged', event => {
      setTemperatureList(t => {
        let temperatureListCopy = t.map(x => x);
        temperatureListCopy.push(event.target.value.getInt16(0))
        if (temperatureListCopy.length > 10)
          temperatureListCopy.shift()
        return temperatureListCopy
      })
    }
  }
  return <button onClick={nofity}/>Start notifications</button>
}
```

This solves the issue as the updater function is only evaluated on events.